# Make Force Boot DVD like Norton Ghost

Tags: boot, window

How to make a Force Boot DVD with custom menu and picture background? What is a force boot DVD? A DVD which does not need to set first boot device on DVD rom or it does not need to launch boot devices with F12 and choose DVD and it loads itself without any config just like Norton Ghost Bootable DVD

Answer (score 2):

A computer's UEFI, or BIOS controls the device boot order, and that cannot be over-ruled. If your hard drive is set to boot before your dvd drive then your hard drive will be booted first, end of story.

Norton Ghost uses WinPE, you can make a custom WinPE disc for free using Micrososfts deployment tools, AIK or the newer WADK. However WinPE is a stripped down version of Windows, and therefore has very limited functionality, you haven't listed what you intend to use this for, but chances are WinPE won't meet your needs unless they're very basic.

You might consider looking into linux live-cds. Ubuntu, or Puppy Linux as they can run more fully fledged software, and are equally as complicated to modify.

Comment: I have a boo-table DVD, just want to run a boot menu with two choices, boot from dvd and boot from hard. and I need to load this boot menu without any other config which I called it force boot.

Comment: @Stranger And should you choose to run the dvd, what do hope to be able to do on it? Many live-cd's include a boot to hard drive option in their menu.